# What happens if OCI (Overseas Citizenship of India) is not renewed?

Tags: india, visa

I am reading conflicting information.

1) OCI is lifelong. YET-

2) OCI is needed to be renewed each time passport is renewed before 21. YET-

3) OCI card holder can travel to India with OCI on old passport without renewing it. [enter link description here](http://www.airindia.in/u-sticker-visa-for-oci-card-holders.htm)

Now, if someone under 21 is living in India, who has OCI on old foreign passport, in India gets foreign passport renewed, but does not renew OCI, is that person's stay in India legal or not ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "OCI". In general it is best to spell out acronyms and abbreviations. Almost every three letter acronym has dozens of possible meanings and it is non-trivial to determine which one you mean.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. This is very helpful.